# Given P(A) = 0.0124 P(B) = 0.01 P(C) = 0.01 find P(A|C). Assuming independence

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve the problem below, assuming conditional independence between A, B, and C.
Given:
P(A) = 0.0124
P(B) = 0.01
P(C) = 0.01
P(A|B) = 0.26
P(A|B') = 0.01
P(B|C) = 0.95
P(B|C') = 0.0005

Find P(A|C)

Derived probabilities also include: P(B|A) = 0.2015, P(B|A') = 0.0076, P(A'|B) = 0.75, P(A|C) = 0.2380, P(A|C') = 0.0101

Comment: This can't be solved without additional assumptions. e.g. if conditional independence of $A$ and $C$ given $B$ is assumed.